# Multiple participant registration not tied to contribution for paid events?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute

When registering multiple participants for a paid event, only the first participant has a contribution attached to them. Each subsequent participant shows up correctly, but has no attached contribution or any payment information.

Checking the `participant_payment` table, no entry is created for the additional participants.

Is there a way to track payments or the contact who registered them for these additional participants?

Examples from the Civi 4.7 Demo site -

**User with contribution:**
[image: User with contribution]

**User without contribution:**
[image: User without contribution]

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this for a good while, I've discovered that clicking the contact name in the "Registered By" field on the additional registrations will bring up the original registration in a modal.

The way it appears now implies that it would take you to that contact's detail page and not their registration.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Price Set for your event fees you will see the above results. Additional participants will show $0 Fees Paid in Event Reports.

However, if you use the Regular Fees > Fee Labels at the bottom of the Event Management > Fees page--on the registration pages, it will show a radio button with the fee amount. This Fee Amount will show below each Participant Profile when registering multiple participants. I have 1 Fee label created and checked "Default" and it automatically has it as required--it cannot be unchecked in the registration process.